# django no matching url with parameters

Tags: django

When the login process is complete, I am trying to redirect the user to their profile page, I am passing the user id to the url, although I get the below error.

Reverse for 'index' with arguments '(2,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'profiles/profile/(?P/d+)/$']

login redirect

```
return redirect('profiles:index',user.id)
```

url expression

```
 url(r'^profile/(?P<user_id>/d+)/$', views.index, name='index'),
```

login view

```
def Login(request):
    form = LoginForm()
    regForm = SignUpForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = authenticate(username=request.POST['login_username'], password=request.POST['login_password'])

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            if 'next' in request.POST:
                return redirect(request.POST['next'])
            #print '----------------------'
            #print user.id
            return redirect('profiles:index',user.id)
        else:
            return render(request, 'index.html',{'error':'The username and password didnt match','form':form,'regForm':regForm})
    else:
         return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form,'regForm':regForm})
```

Main url

```
from django.contrib import admin

from authentication import views
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
        url(r'^authentication/', include('authentication.urls')),
        url(r'^emails/', include('emails.urls')),
        url(r'^profiles/', include('profiles.urls')),
    ]
```

Comment: using this code: `return redirect('profiles:index', user_id=user.id)` and modify forward slash to back slash ` url(r'^profile/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', views.index, name='index'),`

Comment: I tried your code and it still dosnt redirect

Comment: `profiles` namespace exists in root url?

Comment: yeah I have updated my code to show my main urls page

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your url pattern. You should use **`\d+`** in the regex to match digits (note the backslash).

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', views.index, name='index'),
```

Comment: I have corrected the error when I log the user in the page does not redirect, it stays on the login page

Comment: If you're not redirected at all, the problem may be in your login view. We would need more details, maybe in another question.

Comment: the user is logged in succesfully, it dosent redirect at the end though, Ill update my code

Answer (score 0):

using below code:

```
url(r'^profiles/', include('profiles.urls', namespace='profile')), # add namespace to your route
```

Comment: I added namespace and it still does not redirect

Comment: use this code just for test `return redirect('/profiles/profile/2')`

Comment: in browser address bar enter this url: `http://localhost:8000/profiles/profile/2`

Comment: the http request redirected

Comment: user.id has value?

Comment: yeah it has a value of 2